# Virtual Webcam in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, kernel

I want to write a new virtual webcam driver, which for example will take an AVI or live stream for example for screen and stream it as webcam source.

I'll not have webcam really, I want to add a virtual webcam which streams desktop screen.

I should write a webcam in kernel mode to do so ? If so, could you guide me to a sample webcam driver?

If I should do it in DirectShow, how can I add a webcam device to list in webcams list in Control panel, so for example in Yahoo messenger, I can choose that device as webcam and stream my desktop as webcam images.

How can I get started?

Comment: Admit it: you just want to do the old 'Hall of Mirrors' effect...

Comment: DirectShow's Push Source Filters Sample will help given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/push-source-filters-sample

Answer (score 7):

You need to write a DirectShow source filter. The Windows SDK contains a library called *baseclasses* which helps you developing such a filter. See [CSourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921406.aspx) for a good starting point.

To get the device to show up under the other Video Streaming Devices, you have to register your filter with the DirectShow API under the CLSID_VideoInputCategory. You don't need to/shouldn't write a kernel driver.

Comment: Is this valid if I am not writing the code that is finding the camera and reading from. 
Say I implement this, will skype or chrome or any other app find this source when they look for cameras in the system ? I understand that I can register it and later on I can find it in Media Foundation or DirectShow. But would other applications find it from the system. Would it show in list of devices ?

Comment: please help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839449/directshow-based-virtual-camera-is-not-showing-any-frame-in-zoom

Answer (score 2):

You can get start with the sample "amcap" under DirectShow package, it is a excellent sample for beginner. If you want to list webcam devices, go to ChooseDevices() method.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to develop DirectShow Source Filter for creating Virtual camera, Read this first
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/writing-source-filters

Then you can adopt
https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam

You can work on top of this sample virtual camera.

This implements [`IAMStreamConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-iamstreamconfig) and [`IKsPropertySet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/ikspropertyset) interfaces
This is built using [`CSourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/csourcestream) and [`CSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/csource) class which implements [`IPin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-ipin) and [`IBaseFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-ibasefilter)