# Virtual webcam input as byte stream

Tags: c#, c, windows, directshow

I dont have webcam. And I want to implement virtual webcam (or fake device driver may be) that would work as normal webcam(**virtual webcam**) and takes memory stream or bytes as input. How can I develop this? Can DirectShow be helpful in this? I dont know anything. Please help

i have found that there are many software that takes video file  as input but I want to have byte stream as input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a Direct Show Source Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413769/writing-a-direct-show-source-filter)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here you go:

- [DirectShow Source filter using Dekstop window as source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214786/directshow-source-filter-using-dekstop-window-as-source)
- [Writing a Direct Show Source Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413769/writing-a-direct-show-source-filter)
- [Way to generate video from a bunch of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211829/way-to-generate-video-from-a-bunch-of-images-in-netc)
- [Writing a virtual webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243891/writing-a-virtual-webcam)
- [Virtual Webcam in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596424/virtual-webcam-in-c)
- [Virtual Webcam Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627448/virtual-webcam-driver)

More at MSDN Forums:

- [How to render a byte array from socket/application using DirectShow?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/e0294135-239d-4f13-88f5-d73ca8ad7d36)
- [Injecting sample from samplegrabber into a graph](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/1928b399-7ab0-4e52-8332-1ac62a80fbfd)

If you prefer to skip programming and to just install a virtual camera that you don't happen to have available, you can install a [virtual DirectShow camera](http://alax.info/blog/1223) backed by an IP camera put on Internet and continue your DirectShow experience from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243891/writing-a-virtual-webcam seemed to be clearer but I dont get the idea from where to start. I mean What shall I do to write DirectShow Filter that takes bytes as input and gives me output as webcam which later would be listed as normal webcam in any software for video capturing device. Please elaborate it.

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/e0294135-239d-4f13-88f5-d73ca8ad7d36

Comment: I would use DirectShow.NET and then try to call proper functions and pass the args and then maybe use graphedit and register the DLL. am i right?

Comment: Please do research on the subject, it has discussed multiple times. You will need to write a filter in C++, or use a third party filter as a proxy in order to push your data into DirectShow pipeline.