# How to write an own capture filter?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, directshow

Here's a great article on capturing video: http://nerdlogger.com/2011/11/03/stream-your-windows-desktop-using-ffmpeg/ it uses UScreenCapture filter. This time I need to use a custom filter, how to write one? And how to register so that FFmpeg can see that?

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` uses DirectShow video capture devices available in the opreating system, see more details on this forum thread: [DirectShow Capture support](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27).

So you need to make a counterpart virtual source device to be picked up by `ffmpeg`. Your resources are:

- Multiple SO topics - [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream)
- [Windows SDK - PushSource samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [VCam sample - Capture Source Filter](http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an open source one [if you want to go the dshow route]
https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free
Another option would be some type of custom input filter to libav [ffmpeg].

You register it by [in administrator console]
`regsvr32 dll_name.dll`