# How to create a virtual webcam in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, webcam, directshow

I am working on a project in which I want to develop a virtual webcam in C# or C++. I have reviewed many links one of them is following link: [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream)

I am unable to find anything authentic or some sample examples from where I can take a quick start. During my R&D most of the stuff I found was almost 6 years old and related to the Direct Show. Can anyone please guide me from where I can take a quick start on this?

Comment: There's been no changes on the topic during last 6 years, and, actually, not so many changes over last 16 years. The information there is up to date.

Comment: @RomanR do you have any example project related to the virtual webcam? If yes then can you please share it.

Comment: Last link in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10087276/868014) "VCam Sample" leads to [website](http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm) with "Capture Source Filter" link to "vcam.zip" - this is the traditional starting point. Builds against Windows SDK 7.1 which holds necessary base classes. Alternatively, you can use latest Windows 10 SDK and download missing BaseClasses for the VCam project from [MS legacy samples on GitHub](https://github.com/matthew-xnor/win7samples/tree/master/multimedia/directshow).