# Inject Images to WebCam

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, webcam-capture

i need to inject some picture to webcam feed for some android automation test purposes

Here are what i found so far:

1. using 3rd party app - https://splitcam.com/ 
2. found interesting repo on github - https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-transformer

when i see the examples available on poin 2, there's method that could "transform" some `BufferedImage` to the webcam, and then previewing it back via java JPanel.

Sample code for transforming image (taken from the point 2 examples):

```
public BufferedImage transform(BufferedImage image) {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        BufferedImage modified = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g2 = modified.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
        g2.drawImage(IMAGE_FRAME, null, 0, 0);
        g2.dispose();

        modified.flush();

        return modified;
    }
```

Sample code for putting it back to JPanel (taken from the point 2 examples):

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Test Transformer");
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        window.add(panel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

what i need is slighty different than on point 2, i want to modify the webcam feed with some images, and then putting it back to webcam feed. is that possible?

Comment: It might be easier and more reliable to create a virtual webcam than altering an existing webcam's feed.

Comment: @Matthew could show me links that related to this? :D

Comment: this SO questions answer has a lot of links that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream

Comment: @Matthew thanks, gonna check that

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just use a 3rd party app than write your own. There are plenty of streaming applications that are free and allow you to capture your screen, add overlays, animations etc...